# MYSQL spatial query with MBRContains for matching locations within 10 miles

Tags: javascript, mysql, spatial-query

I am trying to setup a database that eventually will be used to search for matching locations within a 10 miles radius. I have found many different ways and references on doing this this but none are helping me much.

I keep finding that I need to setup a polygon or something and searching MBRContains with Spatial indexes before to limit the search.

Documents I found found are very sketchy with information. So what I am asking is:

1) Does it have to be a polygon?
2) How do I setup one with the radius I require.
3) How do I set this to search within the user location (Which I have in lat and lng)
4) Whats best way to setup the MYSQL database?
5) Are there any example code I can look at?

Thanks

Comment: This question will be most likely be voteclosed for being to broad or primarily opinion-based.. Besides questions which ask for a tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: Its because I do not know where to start, I am not asking for someone to do it just point me in the right direction

Comment: MySQL function `ST_Distance_Sphere()` seams to make more sense for what you need.. "Returns the mimimum spherical distance between **two points and/or multipoints on a sphere**, in **meters**, or NULL if any geometry argument is NULL or empty." [source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-convenience-functions.html#function_st-distance-sphere)... Notice it's meters if you need miles you need to convert it.

Comment: ok thanks its somehing for me to look at, thanks

Comment: Sure, but ST_Distance_Sphere is unable to use a SPATIAL index, so it's useless in most cases.